# How to show commits that are about to be pushed

Tags: git

For a `pre-push` hook I want to determine what is about to be pushed.

If the remote branch is known this is trivial because git provides the data via `stdIn` to the hook.
It gets tricky if the remote branch does not exist yet. Then the hook does not receive any useful data. And we are on our own.
Stack overflow has a lot of questions and answers for this topic. Sadly nothing really fitting to the `hook` use case.

**For Example:**

This will fail (since there is no remote/branch yet):

```
git log --oneline {REMOTE}/{BRANCH}..HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument...
```

We could use the local source branch

```
git log --oneline main..feature
```

But this would mean we need to know the source branch. Which we don't in our current hook context and I don't want to guess/hardcode main or master.
So one way to solve this would be to find the commit where the branch was started. And then run

```
git log --online {BRANCH_START}..HEAD
```

We can use the `reflog` to do it but that seems rather unreliable since the `reflog` is forgetting things over time. But this can work, by picking the last commit in the output the following command generates.

```
git reflog {CURRENT_BRANCH}
```

But as mentioned I deem the `reflog` to be rather unreliable.

## Question

Is there another way to find the commit where a branch was created?
Or am I missing a way easier solution to see all changes that are about the be pushed.

--

I played around with `--max-parents` and `--min-parents` but that did not yield any usable results yet.

In order to use `merge-base` you also need to know the source or the branch :/

The end result should be a list of changed files that will be pushed.
But as soon as I have the commits I think I can manage :)

I know there are complicated scenarios where multiple pushes are executed at the same time. But we can ignore those for now.

Comment: You mention stdin so I assume you have read [pre-push](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push). Have you also read `.git/hooks/pre-push.sample`?

Comment: Yes, but the `git rev-list` command that they are using is not working properly. It returns way to much commits in my case: master branch 3 commits, new branch 1 new commit, on push I want to see 1 commit that is new, `rev-list` showing 4 :/

Comment: What is the full command of `git rev-list` in your case? For creating a new branch in the remote repository, the hook calls `git rev-list $local_oid`.  For updating an existing branch, the hook calls `git rev-list $remote_oid..$local_oid`.

Comment: It calls `git rev-list $local_oid` in case there is nothing known about the remote yet. That leads to all commits reachable from the current commit meaning all commits to the beginning of the repo.

Comment: If you push to create a new branch, all of these commits are indeed new to the branch.

Comment: Yes but not new to the repo, and git will not push the already pushed commits because it somehow knows or realizes, not sure how it works. JetBrains IntelliJ´s push view somehow shows the "right/expected" commits.

Comment: Have you installed any plugin or does JetBrains IntelliJ have a feature that fetches the branches and tags automatically in the background? If so, the local repository is always synced with the remote repository as much as possible and thus the push view can make the best guess by `git rev-list $local_oid ^origin/branch1 ^origin/branch2 ^tag1 ^tag2 ...`.

Comment: No plugins. And yes, maybe IntelliJ does something in the background to make it work. But it is extremely fast even for my really big repositories with loads of branches, tags, and commits.

Comment: The simple tactical solution is to push your branch up to remote as soon as you branch off main.

Comment: You could make a script which start of checking if your current branch have a remote, if it has use the remote, if it hasn't use origin/main.